# How to keep a single browser window open during multiple search for a website in the code?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to search for different items in a website multiple times and add the item to cart after each search and proceed to checkout after last search. Cucumber opens the new browser for every row in **Examples** section of **Scenario outline** row. Is it possible to keep a single browser window open during multiple searches for a website?

My feature file is as follows:

```cucumber
    Feature: Search
    
    Scenario Outline: Search and select item
    Given: User is on main page
    Then: User enters <item> and click search
    Then: User sorts the item
    Then: User add the item
    Then: Proceed to checkout

    Examples:
    |item1|
    |item2|
    |item3|
```

Any hints what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Scenario outline, each example is considered as a single scenario with the scenario outline structure.
Think scenario outline as a template where in every example you replace the '<>' with values form each example row and run separately

You could use tables to add multiple items in the same cart separately

```
Scenario: Search and select items
  Given User is on main page
  When User enters, sort and add to cart the following items separately
    |Item1|Item2|Item3|
  Then Proceed to checkout
```

Another way to do this could be something like (in declarative way)

```
Scenario: Search and select items
   Given user is on main page
   When search and add to cart multiple items
   Then proceed to checkout
```

Then you have to resolve internally the *When* step at a step level. This way aims to focus on what you want to describe at user level and not how you do it.

Hope it help